Leaflet-Geoman: Show vertices of all polygons in draw mode
Is there a way to show the vertices of all polygons the way they are shown in edit mode when in draw mode for a new polygon?


The only solution I came up with was to use turf.explode to generate the vertices as points and to display those, but I wonder if there is an easier way or anything i missed in the documentation.
